# Why does my Displacement Map look alien?

Tags: modifiers, displacement, 3d-printing

[image]Why does my displacement map look like an alien landscape? Adjusting strength only lessens the degree, but adding additional sub surface mods causes the system to crash. [image]

round 2
okay so I filled the circle with a grid fill. and was able to subdivide and add a displacement modifier. [image: Here's what it looks like when I try to go the shadersroute] ... the face is too big.. I think I unwrapped and centered  it right.
[image: unwrapping?]

[image: Here is the image with a displacement modifier.. my question now becomes , is there any way to smooth out and make it look less like a rock man. or is the picture quality just too low for that sort of]

[image: and here is the displacement map for people wanting to know.]

Comment: Connect the displacement map directly to the output to see if you aligned it properly with your mesh, also take a screenshot of that so we can see it.

Comment: Sorry very new to this, I assume you mean in the shaders menu? or do you mean  in the  uv unwrap place. a little more clarification may be helpful as to what im trying to do .  I  am attempting to imprint a 3d image onto a small coin shaped object. ...  it is my friends face ..  using the displacement modifier however  only ends up with this blast radius effect.... also in other news... I am apparently inept and finding the  edit question button....

Comment: Impossible to answer without more information. Please show us: what the displacement map looks like.. how you are using it (In a modifier? In displacement shading ?) If too many variables, you can share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Found out how to edit questions.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several incorrect things going on at once here - Firstly, the image you are using for your displacement should be set to *non-color* space (as opposed to *sRGB* as it is in your image). Secondly, if you are using displacement, use a proper *Displacement* node (instead of a *Bump* node). Lastly, it looks like you used a circle for your base mesh which still retains triangles in the center even if it is largely subdivided - try to make sure you are starting with a fully quad-based mesh (circle can be made to quads using grid-fill).

[image: Disp]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH.... Of course there's a grid fill button.. (insert face palm here).  I  have spent so long trying to figure out how get this circle filled....  tried F .... tried alt f... tried alt-f with beauty off ... tried  subdividing just those faces.. then only subdividing just select faces to try and even it out...  I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.. ..

Comment: Make sure to grid fill on an empty (no existing faces) circle. If you do it over an already filled circle, you will still have the original face sitting in the same place as the new grid faces and you will have to select it and delete it afterwards, or you will see z-fighting.

Answer (score 0):

However I am able to answer my own questions easily enough... [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please be so kind and try to formulate your answer in such a way that it is not represented by screenshots alone. This way it will be difficult for other users looking for a solution to find this post. Remember: search engines still need text in this case. Thank you!